# How to make a simple pie chart using Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I am very new to Kendo UI let alone telerik. I have been trying to make a pie chart from my model class using Kendo ui Q3 but am failing and i can find a good example, or a tutorial.

Am stuck and frustrated because i thought it was going to be very easy but it is not the case... please help.

---

This is my Model class.

```
public class FinancialAccount
{
    public virtual int FinancialAccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

I want to sum Loans from the Loan class and also to sum the payments from the payment class and present the whole thing under a financial account.

This is my Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {


        var financialaccounts = db.FinancialAccounts.Include(a=>a.Loans).Include(b=>b.Payments);

        return View(financialaccounts.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult MyFinances()
    {
        var financialaccounts = db.FinancialAccounts.Include(a=>a.Loans).Include(b=>b.Payments);
       // DataSourceResult result =
        return Json(financialaccounts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my view:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Chart<FinancedSociety.Models.FinancialAccount>()
    .Name("chart")
    .Title("Pop In Accounts")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)
    )
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("MyFinances", "Financials")))
    .Series(series => {
        series.Pie(model => model.Payments.Sum(a => a.Amount), model => model.Payments.Select(b => b.Description).ToString());
                  // model => model.Loans.Sum(c=>c.Amount), model => model.Loans.Select(f=>f.Description).ToString());
    })
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("{0:N0}")
    ).Theme("metro")
)
```

I get this errors : Bound columns require a field or property access expression. when i change and not try to access items that are not a collection to the FinancialAccount model class a get a blank area where there should a chart

If you know any complete tutorials, they could be of great help. Kendo UI it's not well documented for starters like telerik extensions for MVC : [www.demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/chart/piechart?theme=metro](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/chart/piechart?theme=metro) , here they show a **view**, **controller** and also the **model** but as for Kendo ui it's just view and controller

Comment: What is your problem? Please be more specific! Do you get some errors? What are these errors? Or do you get some unexpected result? What do get and what should be the expected behavior?

Comment: sorry about that, I get this one : Bound columns require a field or property access expression. when i change and not try to access items that are not a collection to the FinancialAccount model class a get a blank area where there should a chart

Comment: If you know any complete tutorials, they could be of great help. Kendo UI it's not well documented for starters like telerik extensions for MVC : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/chart/piechart?theme=metro , here they show a view, controller and also the model but as for Kendo ui it's just view and controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do the .Sum() or .Select() parts.  You need to create a model (class) that does this for you so that you simply return model.PaymentsSum which has either already been calculated or is calculated in this property of the model.  Don't be discouraged this is the first problem everyone has.  Esentially for all the Kendo controls you needs to pass them flat models (except for TreeView).  When these flat models are constructed though you have access to the full object graph of the database object you are referencing.  It ends up this is the way you want to do most all of MVC so you can use DataAnnotations and put your heavy lifting in the models.  I hope I have helped, Kendo has some quirks but I have been very happy with it on some really large high profile projects.

Comment: @TreyGramann Could you give a sample code containing Sample Viewmodel, Controller and Pie Chart view showing percentages for the sum of each section i.e. each sum of A, B, C categories in a group data?